# Standalone Wordpress form does not post to specified action when fields are populated

Tags: forms, wordpress, post

So this is weird....

I have a form I've created myself (not a plugin, this is what I mean by standalone), and for some strange reason it does **not** post to the form's action when the form fields have data in them. However, when the fields are *empty* it successfully posts to the other page.

I have turned off all validators and really am not sure why this is happening.

Do I need to hook into a Wordpress function to allow for my own form submission?

I realized my permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/` so perhaps it cannot properly post to the URL since it's not an actual file.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses query vars to route the request to posts/pages etc. My guess is that one/some of your field names are used by Wordpress internally.

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars for the list of vars you shouldn't use